# How to select a menu option in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to programming and I don't know how to do this, in Dart:

I want to select the option I am in, in the upper options bar as shown in the image on the left side.

*Development with Flutter, thanks*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use an appbar navigation, from one searched on google or youtube in some tutorials, but the principle of navigation will be practically the same. Here is an example with an `icon` :

```
IconButton(
     tooltip: "Receipt",
     icon: const Icon(Icons.receipt_long),
     onPressed: () {
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, /receipt);
     },
  ),
```